# Can we move the chair when we're playing?

Tags: carrom

While playing carrom, if we're seated in a chair. Can we reposition the chair to play the shot better?

Answer (score 3):

No, you are not allowed to move the chair (nor the table).

According to [this site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/carrom/how_to_play_carrom.htm):

> The players are not allowed to lift and move the chair or table to reposition themselves for strike. However, players can change their positions without moving the seat.